# Использование DestroyEnvironmentBlock в C#

Tags: c#

Народ. Помогайте.
Моя приоритетная задача - удалить командную строку запуска процесса по его PID.
Есть решение на C++, но я не могу его использовать. Совсем. Никак.

Я нашел функцию [DestroyEnvironmentBlock](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/userenv/DestroyEnvironmentBlock.html) в userenv.dll

Как его использовать в C#? Я нигде не нашел примеры применения, т.е. как по PID уничтожить [PEB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Environment_Block) процесса.

Верю в Вашу помощь!

Comment: Имею стойкое мнение что c# для системного программирования категорически не подходит.

Comment: DestroyEnvironmentBlock, кстати, вам не подойдет наверняка: эта функция освобождает память, выделенную внутри  CreateEnvironmentBlock.

Comment: А можно пример использования в C#?

Comment: Нет, потому что я пишу на сях, иногда с ООП. Попробуйте написать прототип на более подходящем языке, наверняка функция не даст того что вы хотите.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, можете добавить меня в скайп? Есть одно дельце. Скайп: antigreefer